# How can I use a Google Script to insert names into formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is used to track student attendance.  I have it set so that I can paste attendance data into one tab, then have formulas in another tab that use "Countifs" to track each student's totals.  I have built all of the formulas manually before, but it takes an incredible about of tedious work.

Is there a script I could use to insert student's names from column A into my formulas?  (See screenshot for reference).  Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiKz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script, you can just use a reference to column `A` to get the name.

Try this:

```
=countifs(Totals!B:B,$A128,Totals!D:D,"1A")
```